# Another Separable Differential Equation , with trig

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks:
Solve the given differential equation by separation of variables

$csc(y)dx + sec^2(x)dy=0$

I have gotten to:

$\dfrac{dy}{csc(y)}=\dfrac{dx}{sec^2(x)}$

$\ln(csc(y))=\ln(sec^2(x))$

Can someone show me how to do this, please?

Comment: I feel it should be $\sec^2(x) dy$ and not dx !

Comment: $$\int \frac{dx}{\sec^{2}(x)} = \int \cos^{2}(x) dx \ne \ln(\sec^{2}(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

The cosecant is the reciprocal of the sine and the secant is the reciprocal of the cosine, so you can write your equation as
$$
\sin y\,dy=\cos^2x\,dx
$$

In general, the integral of $1/f(x)$ is *not* $\log|f(x)|$ except in the simple case of $f(x)=x+k$.

Comment: You meant the simple case $f(x)=x+b$.

Comment: @Galc127 Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
$$\dfrac{dy}{\csc y}=\dfrac{dx}{\sec^2x}\implies \int \sin y\  dy=\int \cos^2 x \  dx  $$

Can you proceed from here ?

Answer (score 0):

You got $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{\csc(y)}=-\frac{dx}{\sec^2(x)}$. Now we need to integrate, hence $$\int{\frac{dy}{\csc(y)}}=-\int{\frac{dx}{\sec^2(x)}}\Rightarrow \int{\sin(y)dy}=-\int{\cos^2(x)dx}=-\frac{1}{2}\int{1+\cos(2x)}dx$$

These two integrals are immediate and finally $$\cos(y)=-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C\Rightarrow y=\arccos(-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C)$$